# How to use Google Sign In and phone Camera with Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, camera

I'm trying to build an app that relies heavily on camera usage, however I'm having difficulty adding sign-in options. I have email and password set up through FirebaseAuth, but when I try to set up the Google login using the google_sign_in package, I get this error:

```
Because google_sign_in >=4.5.0 <5.0.0-nullsafety depends on
google_sign_in_platform_interface ^1.1.1 which depends on quiver
^2.0.0, google_sign_in >=4.5.0 <5.0.0-nullsafety requires quiver
^2.0.0. And because camera >=0.8.0 depends on quiver ^3.0.0,
google_sign_in >=4.5.0 <5.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with camera
>=0.8.0.
```

Is there a different way to implement google sign in or camera usage?

Info:
This is my dependencies section in pubspec.yaml.

```
  dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  uuid: 3.0.4
  gato: ^0.0.4
  camera: ^0.9.2+2
  quiver: ^2.0.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  # Google Firebase
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.5

  
  # State Management
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your packages depend on each other. For example, for your camera dependency to work, it relies on quiver package over ^3.0.0 but yours is ^2.0.0. Go through your dependencies and update them

Comment: Use google_sign_in 5.1.0